# Unusual behavior in c++ program, crashing often

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

**I've recently hit an issue in my program and it seems as if nobody has had this problem either, I've scoured the internet for a solution but I just couldn't find it, let me explain.**

## The issue

I've been working on a 2D platforming game for a while now and am slowly implementing new features, however, I've it hit a snag. I'm currently programming a AABB tree implementation into my game for collision and physics purposes and it seems to be causing lots of trouble. I eventually fixed all the errors in the program and got a working implementation, at least, I thought I did until random errors started popping up. To my surprise, it wasn't actually my AABB class at all, it was this single block of code.

```
while (fs.tellg() < Size) {
    unsigned short int x, y, w, h;
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), 2);//I'm reading from a binary
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&y), 2);//file containing the AABB
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&w), 2);//rectangle points
    fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&h), 2);// x,y, width,height

    //These are the two lines where the error occurs
    unsigned nodeNum = tree.allocateNode(x*35, y*35, w*35, h*35);
    tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum); //Here is where it crashes                                   

};
```

But hold your horses, this isn't the full story...

---

### The weird part

As I diagnosed this error I came across a few interesting things.

**1.** The program actually runs perfectly a small percentage of the time. I set 
       up a `system("pause");` at the end of the commands to see if it will run 
       and it did! It also immediately crashed after I hit enter to past the 
       pause block.

**2.** This for some reason works just fine

```
unsigned nodeNum = tree.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum);

unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
unsigned nodeNum3 = tree.allocateNode();

tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum3);
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);
```

But then this doesn't work at all, it actually crashes the program.

```
unsigned nodeNum = yahh.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum);

unsigned nodeNum2 = yahh.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);

unsigned nodeNum3 = yahh.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum3);
```

This works too.

```
unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);

unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
//tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);
```

But this doesn't. It seems as if calling the `allocateNode();` and 
`insetLeaf();` commands twice in order crashes the program...

```
unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);

unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);
```

#### Source Code

**AABBtree.h**

```
#define AABB_NULL_NODE 0xffffffff

struct AABBNode {
    unsigned nodeNum;
    //AABBNode(unsigned _newNode) : _newNode(nodeNum) { };
    ~AABBNode(){ };
};
//==========================================================================
//==========================================================================
class AABBtree {
private:
    unsigned _rootNode = AABB_NULL_NODE;
    std::vector<AABBNode> _nodeTable;
public:
    AABBtree() { };
    ~AABBtree(){ };

    unsigned allocateNode() {
        //Allocate node and return new Node index
        unsigned nodeNum = _nodeTable.size();
        _nodeTable.emplace_back(nodeNum);
        return nodeNum;
    };

    void insertLeaf(unsigned& nodeNum) {
        AABBNode& newNode = _nodeTable[nodeNum];

        //Allocate a new AABB, it will be curNode and newNode new parent.
        unsigned newParentIndex = allocateNode();
        AABBNode& newParent = _nodeTable[newParentIndex];
    };
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
AABBtree tree;
int main() {
    unsigned nodeNum = tree.allocateNode();
    tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum);
    unsigned nodeNum2 = tree.allocateNode();
    tree.insertLeaf(nodeNum2);
};
```

I've cut most of the parts out to just the bare minimums

Comment: "*The program actually runs perfectly a small percentage of the time*" - wild guess - you have some UB in your code. Additional note: get familiar with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) concept. Please try to shorten your code to meet the requirements of the **minimal** part

Comment: This is going to sound really stupid, but make absolutely certain that `short int` is 16 bits on your system. Prefer a `uint16_t` so you get guarantees.

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I'm new to this site in terms of posting. I'll shorten it down to the bare minimums.

Comment: You should also include the error you get. Saying it crashes will not get you much help

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @Waneden Being new is not an excuse to not taking the [tour], and reading through [ask], and [help].

Comment: I agree with Fureeish. question seems to be legit. Followup comments. End of review. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Also prefer [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) over `unsigned`

Comment: You're not using threads by any chance?

Comment: @immibis yes and those were where the errors were occuring. When I commented out those suspected lines the program ran through just fine.

Comment: @markRansom Nope.

Comment: @Waneden [Does not compile](https://www.ideone.com/jFXRVi)

Comment: I think the problem is in your `insertLeaf` method. I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has to do with a dangling reference and here is my reason: Note that a vector can resize itself when it gets to a certain threshold. When it does this, any references to objects within the vector are invalidated, so with respect to `AABBNode& newNode = _nodeTable[nodeNum];`, this `newNode` might become invalid after `unsigned newParentIndex = allocateNode();` is called. Remove the `&` beside the variables and make a copy instead and see if the error is still there

Comment: @smac89 You should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem has to do with your `insertLeaf` method.

```
void insertLeaf(unsigned& nodeNum) {
    AABBNode& newNode = _nodeTable[nodeNum];

    //Allocate a new AABB, it will be curNode and newNode new parent.
    unsigned newParentIndex = allocateNode();
    AABBNode& newParent = _nodeTable[newParentIndex];
}
```

This method first acquires a reference to an object inside the vector (`_nodeTable`).

Next it makes a call to `allocateNode()`. Within the `allocateNode` method, it calls [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) on the vector which will potentially increase the size of the `_nodeTable`.

---

Herein lies the problem - If the vector has to do a resize due having reached it's capacity, then you have lost the reference which you had before calling `allocateNode`. You now have what is known as a *dangling reference* i.e. a reference which is not bound to an object in memory.

If `_nodeTable` resizes after that call to `emplace_back`, then back in your `insertLeaf` method, you now have an invalid node reference.

#### Quick fix

- Force the vector to reserve enough memory before taking that reference. You can use the [`std::vector::capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) method in addition to [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).